# Refunding with a gas price lower than the minimum unit

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core, account-abstraction, safe

When calling execTransaction the gasPrice argument is an uint256 which means that the minimum amount that we can send is 1. For an ERC20 with 6 decimals (like USDC) this would represent 0.000001. Sometimes the actual gas price denominated in USDC could actually be less than that, for example in Polygon, if gas price = 130 gwei, then that is ~0.00000008 USDC <  0.000001

This means that the refund the wallet ends up paying could be much greater than what it actually should. Do you think there could be a workaround? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue regarding the repayment feature. There are plans to remove it from the core contract.
Meanwhile, in the Safe{Core} SDK we are handling this by creating a batch transaction from the Safe with two transactions: the regular one and the one used to repay the relay.

Comment: Thanks! This is what we ended up doing :)